# How do I create a segment from my custom goals in Google Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics

I have some custom goals in GA based on certain events.

For example, scroll 75% of page, video play, social share, a link click to another article etc. are all classed as goals. All together they these are classed engaged users.

Now, I want to see how these engaged users interact with my content (in Behaviour > Site Content > All pages).

How do I create a custom segment that is made up of these goals? I tired clicking on 'Add Segment' > 'New Segment' but I can't find any options to add these goals/events.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Click on Add Segment > New Segment, then select Conditions.
In the right page on the segment builder, select Sessions or Users and Include, then below that in the section to select a dimension or metric, select it and start typing in the name of one of your goals, it will be in blue, as it is a metric (dimensions are in green) and from there configure your segment.

More info on how to build custom segments can be found in the GA Help Center
https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/3124493?hl=en

Comment: Amazing! Thank you!